# Get запросы в питоне (и не только)

Tags: python, json, парсер, request

Пытаюсь получить данные в json с помощью get запроса, с сайта где стоит фаерволл incapsula, пытаясь это сделать через приложение на смартфоне (которое не передает запросу ни user-agent, ничего), все прекрасно работает, и запрос прилетает в json. Но когда отправляю запрос в python
С помощью requests, прилетает ответ от incapsula. Так же пытался передавать user-agent, все безуспешно, но сколько бы не спамил со смартфона, ответ всегда приходит. Есть ли пути решения?
[Ссылка для теста](https://www.copart.com/public/data/lotdetails/solr/lotImages/55300089/)

[image: Скриншот с приложения]

Comment: Покажите код с requests, который не работает?

Comment: Нужно использовать что-то типа Selenium. Проблема в том, насколько читал раньше, что сначала приходит js, который делает чек-ап броузера, после чего выдается уже сам json.

Comment: Да я про селениум вкурсе, тут дело в скорости... Почему-то на мобильных то приходит ответ, а тут